# (node:31199) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

Tags: terminal

When I open up terminal, the following message appears

```
(node:31199) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
```

How can I fix it so that it disappears?

STEPS TAKEN
I have looked through similar questions posted on SO but have still not been able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This Error from my experince with an old project it is related to an old node version / project that you are trying to run, install. If possible please try to update your node version, then reinstall "npm install"